# Python Crash Course 19-1 project troubles

Tags: python, django

> 19-1. Blog: Start a new Django project called Blog. Create an app called blogs in the project and a model called BlogPost. The model should have fields like title, text, and date_added. Create a superuser for the project, and use the admin site to make a couple of short posts. Make a home page that shows all posts in chronological order.
> Create a form for making new posts and another for editing existing posts. Fill in your forms to make sure they work.

I'm having issues trying to show the blog post title as well as the paired body of text underneath it. My current setup is showing the correct titles in order, but it's only showing the last entry for each bullet.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Blog_post(models.Model):
    """ Create new blog post """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        """ Return string representation of the title"""
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```
"""  Define URL patterns for blog_app """
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'blog_app'
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),     
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Blog_post

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    """ Home page for blog """
    posts = Blog_post.objects.order_by('date')
    #entry = posts.objects.get('body')
    for i in posts:
        entry = i.body
    context = {'posts': posts, 'entry': entry}
    return render(request, 'blog_app/index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
<p> Welcome to my blog page!</p>

{% block content %}
 <p> posts: </p>
 
  <ul>
   {% for post in posts  %}
     <li>
      {{ post }}
      {{ entry|linebreaks }}
     </li>
   {% empty %}
    <li> No Topics have been added yet.</li>
   {% endfor %}
  </ul>
   
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are overwriting `entry` in a for loop. In your `views.py`:

```py
    for i in posts:
        entry = i.body
    context = {'posts': posts, 'entry': entry}
    return render(request, 'blog_app/index.html', context)
```

After the for loop executes, `entry` will contain the last `i.body`.

You could do something like this in your template:

```
{% for post in posts  %}
     <li>
      {{ post.title }}
      {{ post.body|linebreaks }}
     </li>
   {% empty %}
    <li> No Topics have been added yet.</li>
   {% endfor %}
```

and you can then remove the `entry` context variable from `views.py`.